# Automatically calling a contract function every 24 hours?

Tags: solidity, oracles, oraclize

I want to have my smart contract call a function every 24 hours automatically. Can this be achieved as follows?

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.2;    

import "http://github.com/oraclize/ethereum-api/oraclizeAPI_0.4.sol";

contract MyContract is usingOraclize {

    function callThisToStart() {
        oraclize_query(1*day, "URL", "");
    }

    function __callback(bytes32 myid, string result) {
        if (msg.sender != oraclize_cbAddress()) throw;
        doSomething();
        callThisToStart();
    }

    function doSomething() {
        // then this should run every 24 hours
    }

}
```

I don't understand how Oracle works yet so this may be completely wrong - `callThisToStart()` would be called, which would then run the `__callback` function a day later, which will then run some code in `doSomething()` and call `callThisToStart()` afterwards so the process would be repeated in a day.

Answer (score 2):

It should work. Have a look [at this example](https://github.com/oraclize/ethereum-examples/blob/6e18f81e657e38dc014fd38ce566e71917411353/solidity/KrakenPriceTicker.sol#L28).

The example just adds a clean check:

> ```
> function update() payable {
>         if (oraclize.getPrice("URL") > this.balance) {
>             newOraclizeQuery("Oraclize query was NOT sent, please add some ETH to cover for the query fee");
>         } else {
>             newOraclizeQuery("Oraclize query was sent, standing by for the answer..");
>             oraclize_query(60, "URL", "json(https://api.kraken.com/0/public/Ticker?pair=ETHXBT).result.XETHXXBT.c.0");
>         }
>     }
> ```