# Are arguments from Provable callback's function mandatory?

Tags: oracles, provable

Since I am only using Provable (formerly Oraclize) in order to make a cron job, and calling only a function from inside my smart contract (like [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/27320/automatically-calling-a-contract-function-every-24-hours)), I was wondering if the parameters `myid` and `result` were mandatory.

So my question is, if I have no need for external API call results, can I just write this?

```
function __callback() public {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course not, because your contract should inherit from contract `usingProvable` (formerly `usingOraclize`) and override this function ([the solc 0.4.x version](https://github.com/provable-things/ethereum-api/blob/master/provableAPI_0.4.25.sol#L369) or [the solc 0.5.x version](https://github.com/provable-things/ethereum-api/blob/master/provableAPI_0.5.sol#L377)).

Hence any such attempt would result with a compilation error.

Of course, you could always edit contract `usingProvable` itself, but that would be even worse, because Provable's server calls this function, ans so you'd be breaking the API that this server relies on.

Hence any such attempt would result with your contract receiving no updates from the off-chain service.